# DataContract create in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

At client side, I have this class without `[DataContract]`:

```
public class UserEntity
    {
        public string login;
        public string password;
    }
```

when I put `[DataContract]` and refresh the reference of this class at WCF side, then I can't initiate the web service. It says an error:

> cannot create metadata...

What's wrong?

Comment: are you adding [DataMember] to your public fields, too?? Either you leave all the attributes off, then the DataContractSerializer behaves much like the old XmlSerializer - or if you start adding attributes, you have to add them all - you cannot just mix and match and add a few of the attributes....

Comment: Classes with the `DataContract` attribute are to be defined in the WCF service. After you reference the service, you can then instanciate your class and pass it back and forth.

Comment: this Entity is in a WCF Class library at Client Side, there is no compiler error.
I'm just putting [DataContract] above the "public class UserEntity"
Anything wrong? Do I have to put [DataMember] next to the attributes too?
Thank you.

Comment: I tried to put [DataMember] and it didnt work...
"Cannot obtain metada..."

Comment: @Alan: you need to do your updates to your **service** and then update your clients - updates just on the client side aren't really recognized and can cause client and server to be out of sync.

Comment: @Alan: a couple of questions:  1) do you have a metadata endpoint defined for this service?  2) How are you using this class?  You're defining it on the client -- it's not defined on the service side?  Also, if you can post your configuration settings, that also may help.

Comment: Oh, now i did it work. Now my entities are in WCF side. But I have a problem. I want to make a DAO Library, and Entity Library. If I make a entity library, i can't access it by WCF =/
Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you actually know, why you can't refresh the reference? I mean you add [DataMember] - and it fails, you remove it - it works? Or it works several days ago and now you add [DataMember] (and many other stuff) and it not works now?

But anyway, the easiest way to solve "refresh reference" issues - to refresh reference manually with SvcUtil.exe. In this case error message would be much more descriptive the simple "oops! error!".

Comment: yes, i'm really sure that only when I add [DataContract], it gives the error. But I already solved by putting the Entity at WCF side.
But at WCF side I cant create a Library for Entities and a Library for DAO. Is this common?

Comment: You may "crash" it again and try to refresh reference with SvcUtils. It shows you, what wrong. 

In my application I use shared assembly for server and client (I know, that isn't truly SOA-way but it easier for me)... But maybe I don't understand your position about "Library for Entities":)

Answer (score 0):

What is client and server side in your case? What is refreshing reference on the WCF side? Your description is very uncommon. Here is description how to create service with complex data type and WCF Class library:

- Create WCF class library
- Add data contract to the class library
- Add service to class library
- Implement service contract and service in the class library
- Add host project
- Reference WCF class library from host project
- Host service from class library in host project
- Add Metadata endpoint to your hosted service
- Create client project
- Run the host project outside the visual studio
- Use Add service reference to create proxy on WCF service hosted in your host project
- Implment code to call your service through created proxy

As you see there is no modification of data contract on the client side and no refreshing WCF service.